# A good iOS app to learn Medieval French

Tags: histoire, ressources

Any advice for someone who wants to get started on Medieval French?

I would like to hear about some suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there already is an iOS app to learn Medieval French, but there is a website translating Old French. Here is the link:

http://www.lexilogos.com/francais_dictionnaire_ancien.htm

Hope it can help.